# bootstrap issue in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins Version 1.545 and Sonarqube Version 4.2.When I execute Sonarqube analysis using jenkins build,my build fails with the following error:- 
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project : Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=abc.project:abc.project-java:javascript: Read timed out.
This cannot be a network issue because sonar and jenkins are on same server.
This was intermittent issue earlier but has now become very frequent.
Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Comment: can anyone please reply ?

Comment: Can we have an answer for this question ? Any possible workaround for it except for re-running the build.

Comment: Why is there no reply ?